# how to solve a function problem in which we have to write a greater integer number which is not present in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, variables

Write a function:

function solution(A);

that, given an array A of N integers, returns the smallest positive integer (greater than 0) that does not occur in A.

For example, given A = [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2], the function should return 5.

Given A = [1, 2, 3], the function should return 4.

Given A = [−1, −3], the function should return 1.

Answer (score 0):

function solution(A) {

```
let smallest; //The smallest integer not found in the array

//loop starting from the smallest possible positive integer (1)
//until the greater integer possible (length + 1)
for(i = 1; i<=A.length + 1; i++){
    if(!A.includes(i)){
        //if the integer isn't found in the array, then you return it
        return smallest = i
    }
}
```

}